# imprimir e somar todos os números primos menores ou iguais a um determinado número N no visualg

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, visualg, portugol, pseudocódigo

Estou com dificuldades na parte da soma ao final.

Sou novato em programação e gostaria de ajuda.

Consigo listar os números primos mas não soma-los ao final e apresenta-los

Meu código:

```
Var

c,i,n,p : inteiro

Inicio

escreva("Digite um número:")

leia(n)

para c de 1 até n faca

p <-0

para i de 1 até c faca

se (c mod i=0) então

p <-p+1

fimse

fimpara

se(p=2) então

escreva(c)

fimse

fimpara

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: pq não cria uma variável para soma, por exemplo "s", e logo depois do `escreva(c)` faz `s <- s+c` ?

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição! Cada dia aprendendo mais um pouco hehe

Answer (score -3):

```
Var

N: inteiro

soma:inteiro

i:inteiro

u: inteiro

teste: logico



Inicio

escreva("digite o número inicial: ")

leia(N)

escreva("")

para i de N ate 2 passo -1 faca

u <- i

teste <- verdadeiro

repita

se (u<>i) e (u<>1) e (i mod u = 0) entao

teste <- falso

fimse

u <- u-1

ate u <= 1

se teste = verdadeiro entao

escreval(" O número ", i ," é primo.")

soma <- soma+i

fimse

fimpara

escreval()

escreva("A soma de todos os números primos menores iguais a ", N ," é: ", soma)

Fimalgoritmo
```